# link_to custom action but wrong method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

all, I'm trying to get a custom action to work with a put method: in the

in _post.html.erb i have a link_to statement:

```
<%= link_to 'End now', post, :method => :put, :action => endnow %>
```

routes.rb contains:

```
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put :endnow
    end
```

and posts_controller.rb looks like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :endnow

  [.. code for create, edit, destroy, etc ..]

  def endnow
    puts params
  end

end
```

rake routes's relevant line looks like:
endnow_post PUT    /posts/:id/endnow(.:format) posts#endnow

However, the action endnow helper doesn't run when clicking on this link. 
Strangely, it does run with an index action (which i can tell from the puts command.
Of course, eventually the code for endnow will update @post, but for now, it just doesn't run properly.

Maybe i'm going about this the wrong way - all I'm trying to achieve is to update @post upon clicking the link to that post, and before showing it.

Any ideas / Alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use the route helper method provided to you? Change your link to

```
<%= link_to 'End now', endnow_post_path(@post), method: :put %>
```

Things you're doing wrong:

1. If you want to specify the `:action`, use the Symbol for the action (you're missing a colon).  `:action => endnow` should be `action: :endnow`
2. I will assume you have a `@post` instance variable you're passing from your controller to your action. You should be using that instead of `post` (unless you do in fact have a local `post` variable you're omitting from your code)
3. You are using `endnow` as an action; you should remove the `helper_method :endnow` line in your controller because it's not something you want to/should be accessing from your view.

This can all be avoided by using the route helper (for `endnow_post` you'd append `_path` to get the local route path: `endnow_post_path`), and pass in your `@post` as an argument.

Because you're trying to do a `PUT` request, you must make sure you have something like [`jquery-ujs`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) included in your asset pipeline to convert these links to form submissions behind the scenes; browsers don't support `PUT` via the click of a link on their own.

---

As for why you're getting the template error when you get your `link_to` working, Rails is telling you that you need to create a `app/views/posts/endnow.html.erb` file. Your action has only `puts params` which does not terminate execution, leaving Rails to assume you still are trying to render some `endnow.html.erb` template.

---

Are there other ways to do what you're trying to do (change a single attribute of a specific model)? Sure. Are there **better** ways? That's pretty subjective; it may not be the most RESTful way, but it's arguably easier to deal with (if for example there are very specific authorization rules to check before updating the attribute you are modifying in `endnow`. Does the way you've started fleshing out work? **Absolutely.**

Finally, as a bump in the right direction, after you fix your `link_to` and remove the the `helper_method` as I have described above, your `endnow` action might look like this:

```
def endnow
  post = Post.find!(params[:id])

  post.some_attribute_here = some_new_value_here
  post.save

  redirect_to :root and return # <- this line sets a redirect back to your homepage and terminates execution, telling rails to do the redirect and **not** to render some endnow.html.erb file
end
```

Comment: So obviously I'm communicating badly - I don't really need and 'endnow' action per se, all that's required is that when the link is clicked, a field in the relevant post record is updated. Adding an action is the only way I thought of doing this, but maybe i'm wrong. Of course, I get a template-is-missing error when using your uppermost suggestion (changing the link_to)..

Comment: I've updated my answer for you to provide a bit more help. IMO, anything more is outside of the scope of this question.